# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, sqlite

```
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: employees,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return generateList(List<Employee>.from(snapshot.data));
                  
                }
                
                if (snapshot.data == null || !snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text('No Employee Found');
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  
  SingleChildScrollView generateList(List<Employee> employees) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
```

error occur in return generateList(**snapshot.data**); ******************************
same result if changed to return generateList(List.from(**snapshot.data**));

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cast `snapshot.data` to the `Iterable<dynamic>` type?

```
return generateList(List<Employee>.from(snapshot.data as Iterable<dynamic>));
```